# LaTeX + Biblatex: Author and Special Char result in an "Extra }"

Tags: biblatex

maybe someone can help me ... here is a short example:

## file: sample.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,bibstyle=alphabetic,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblio}
\begin{document}
Referenz zu \cite{HA:02}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

## file: biblio.bib

```
@phdthesis{HA:02,
  author = {{H{\aa}rd af Segerstad}, Ylva},
  //author = {{H\r{a}rd af Segerstad}, Ylva},
  //author = {{Hard af Segerstad}, Ylva},
  //author = {H{\aa}rd af Segerstad, Ylva},
  year = {2002},
}
```

**Expected**
first name = Ylva
last name = Hård af Segerstad

Therefore, the label should be "[Har02] Ylva Hård af Segerstad" (see example 1 and 2).

**Result (Sample 1 and 2)**

```
! Argument of \OT1\r has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.33 \endentry
```

Sample 3 and 4 works, but

- **sample 3**: last name is "Hard af Segerstad" but without an "å"
- **sample 4**: works with "å" but the the last name seems to be "Segerstad" because the label is "[Seg02] and not "[Har02]"

**How can the last name grouped as "Hard af Segerstad" with an "å"??**

Answer (score 2):

The braces should go around the middle part of the last name:

```
@phdthesis{HA:02,
  author = {H{\aa}rd{ af }Segerstad, Ylva},
  year = {2002},
}
```

You can find one or two author names like this in `biblatex-examples.bib` from the documentation.

Comment: @user25210 No problem.

Comment: Wouldn't UTF-8 input be beneficial?

Comment: @egreg It would, but not with (8-bit) BibTeX.

Comment: @Audrey : Valid, though OP is using BibLaTeX

Comment: @Brent.Longborough I assumed the OP has reasons for sticking with Ascii.